# Devas(Gods) and their digestive system

Tags: vedas, puranas, brahma, gods

According to Brahmanda purana, brahma commensed creation in this following chronological order [Bh Purana - Quote 25 - 50].

**Prākrta Creations (pertaining to Prakruti)**

1. Mahat -- Great Principle
2. Tanmatras -- Subtle Elements
3. Vaikārika -- Creation pertaining to Sense organs

**Vaikrta -Mediated creations**

1. Mukhya Sarga  --  Insentients or immobiles
2. Tiryak srota [Beings whose digestive fluids flows obliquely]  -- Animals and lower creatures.
3. **Ūrddhva Srotas [Beings whose digestive fluids flows upwards]  -- Devas, Gandharvas etc**
4. Arvāksrotas [Beings whose digestive fluids flows Downwards]  -- Human beings

Mind born sons of brahmas are classified separately.

Devas are repeatedly mentioned in various scriptures that they are free from death (till manvantara), hunger and diseases. Also in vedas they quote that, Indra and other devatas drink copious amount of somarasa. All picturization of devas looks to be having humane form in divine bodies.

**My Question is, why does devas are classified as Ūrddhva Srotas?**

Intensive googling didn't help me out on this aspect.

Comment: The physical body is the annamayakosa, it refers to the alimentary canal, the canal for eating. In some places in scripture the gods are referred to as having physical bodies. Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said that the subtle body resembles the physical body with limbs, etc. Many of the pictures of the devas were derived from the actual experiences of people.

Comment: Interesting question, especially considering that as far as I know, animals' digestive fluids flow the same way as humans' digestive fluids.  And it's strange for gods to have digestive fluids at all, since presumably any ingesting of Soma can be done by magic.  In any case, what chapter of the Brahmanda Purana is this from?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I dont think devas are being just exists on subtle bodies.Whenever we hear stories someone ascended to heaven , it is always mentioned that , he got a divine body on top of his subtle bodies attached to soul. Even people of vaikunta seems to be having bodies similar to narayana with 4 hands , which is again a body top of soul.

Characteristics of these physical bodies might be different.I believe that is suitable for environment in devaloka.

Comment: @keshav
It is mentioned in 42nd quote , in 5th chapter. It is mentioned again and again in multiple places. One first occurance is following. """Even as he was pondering, the final creation of the Sāttvika type was evolved. This third creation is Ūrdhvasrotas upwards currented , It is based upwards."""

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan . Animals fluids do flow in the same way as humans. But direction is oblique due to structure of their vertebral column attached to digestive tracts.

Comment: Good question. Just a vague guess from my side, does it relate something to what we offer to Gods in the form of sacrifices in Yagnas. Whatever is being sacrificed in the holy fire is being burned down and goes 'up' in form of smoke. Generally people offering food items in Yagnas believe that if a food item is burnt, it is being accepted. If there is any material that discusses about how the Yagyahuti works, may be it can help solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

**Linga Purana**:

> **1.70.147-148. This third creation is Ūrdhvasrotas which is directed upwards. Since it functions upwards it is called Ūrdhvasrotas. The beings created under this category are mostly happy and delighted. They are enshrouded within and without as well as illuminated on both sides.**
>
> **1.70.149. Because they have been created with the union of Sattvaguṇa, they are known as originating from Sattva. This third creation of Ūrdhvasrotas is that of Devas.**
>
> **1.70.150. The creations originating in the category of Ūrdhvasrotas are brilliant within and without. The Ūrdhvasrotas creations are stated by the learned to be satisfied souls.**
>
> **1.70.151. When Devas, the creations in the category of Ūrdhvasrotas were created, Brahmā, the lord who grants boons, became delighted, but he still meditated on another creation.**

The next verse distinguishes Urdhvasrotas from Arvāksrotas:

> **1.70.152-153. He pondered over the creation that will be Sādhaka (active and fit for action). Even as he was meditating truthfully, the active Arvāksrotas creation manifested itself from the unmanifest Prakṛti. Since it functions downwards it is called Arvāksrotas.**

What this means is the Devas do not act; humans do. Devas are immersed in bliss. They are unreachable unless we perform actions, which is the purpose of humans. Those immersed in bliss do not act and cannot. It is the place of the Self. The Self, itself, does not act but actions are necessary to perform to realise it. This is the purpose of Arvāksrotas or Sādhakas. Ordinarily, we are not united to Sattva; we have to perform actions to achieve this and disentangle ourselves from Rajas and Tamas. So, the text is saying that the Devas are sattvic. Those who make themselves sattvic reach their abode, which is blissful.